# Ubuntu 16.10 Radeon RX 470

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

I have Ubuntu 16.10 and my GPU is Sapphire Nitro+ Radeon RX 470 8GB OC.
I cannot find driver for my GPU. I cant install AMDGPU-PRO Driver for Linux, because this driver support just Ubuntu 16.04

What I have to do?
Thanks

Comment: It should work as well in 16.10 provided yours is one of the supported cards. Please check and confirm that before anything else. Anyway,you already have a working driver, either `radeon` or `amdgpu` (most likely). You don't need anything else and `amdgpu-pro` is still experimental.

Comment: In ubuntu 16.04 it works. I had  intalled this driver.  When I try install driver:                                                                                                root@ubuntuOS:/home/user/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864# ./amdgpu-pro-install 
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/amdgpu-pro-uninstall': File exists

Comment: I wrote a guide for getting AMDGPU-PRO 16.40 to work on Ubuntu 16.10: https://www.sabeltand.net/amdgpu-1610/

Comment: 6 months later... Is this still the case? @user1372513, nice job! Just installed Ubunto 16.10 (wish I just installed 16.04)